# create appasset just for one page in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii2, assets

I use yii2 framework.

I want use just one css file in my page, but when I put my css file in appasset.php file as below:

```
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [ 'css/site.css', 'css/country.css', 'css/admin/one.css', 'css/fg/two.css' ]; 
    public $js = [ ]; 
    public $depends = [ 'yii\web\YiiAsset', 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset', ];
```

My page uses all css file  (sit.css, one.css, two.css) but I want just one.css in this my page and I use other css file in other page.

I emphasize again: I want use just one.css file in this my page and don't want use and load other file that is in appasset(two.css and...)

Is it possible to create a new appasset.php file just for one.php page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `AppAsset` is just a convention, there's nothing special about it: you can create any number of other assets like `OneAsset` and `TwoAsset` that only define a single CSS file and load those into your view.

Alternatively, if you are only registering a single CSS file on your page, you could load it into the view manually without using an asset: `$this->registerCssFile('css/one.css')`.